# using ingres driver with sql maven plugin

Tags: maven, sql-maven-plugin

I want to use  [celerio](http://www.jaxio.com/en/celerio.html) to generate code from our database. Celerio uses the [sql-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/) to connect to the database. But i cannot resolve the dependency for the ingres driver.

that's how i set up my database connection in the pom.xml of my celerio project

```
<!-- ingres jdbc driver -->
<jdbc.groupId>ingres</jdbc.groupId>
<jdbc.artifactId>ingres-connector-java</jdbc.artifactId>
<jdbc.version>10.0-4.0.6</jdbc.version>     

<!-- ingres jdbc settings -->
<jdbc.driver>com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver</jdbc.driver>
<jdbc.url>jdbc:ingres://bjax:/entw_frm_db</jdbc.url>
<jdbc.user>ingres</jdbc.user>
<jdbc.password></jdbc.password>
<jdbc.catalog></jdbc.catalog>
<hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.IngresDialect</hibernate.dialect>
<sql-maven-plugin.delimiter>;</sql-maven-plugin.delimiter>
```

but when i try to get the codegen running `>mvn -Pdb,metadata,gen` then i get this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (Create and initialize the database) on project book_application: Execution Create
 and initialize the database of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5 or one of its dependen
cies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:jar:1.5 -> ingres:ingres-connector-java:jar:10.0-4.0.6: Failed
to read artifact descriptor for ingres:ingres-connector-java:jar:10.0-4.0.6: Could not transfer artifact ingres:ingres-connector-java:pom:10.0-4.0.6 from/to Cod
ehaus Snapshots (https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/in
gres/ingres-connector-java/10.0-4.0.6/ingres-connector-java-10.0-4.0.6.pom. Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Gateway. -> [Help 1]
```

NOTE: i tried to run the code generation with mysql and i had no problems at all (but using mysql is no option, because that was only a test - our customers database is a ingres database)

Comment: `Failed to transfer file: https://nexus.codehaus.org/...` Seems like you configured the Codehaus repository, but it is no longer available. See: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217611787-codehaus-org-Repositories-Should-Be-Removed-From-Your-Nexus-Instance

Comment: @PierreB. that seems reasonible. how can i get rid of the repository? it's referred from the pom.xml template that comes from celerio (http://www.jaxio.com/en/celerio.html)

Comment: @PierreB. i got rid of the repository by deleting my local repository and removing the repository from the template pom.xml from celerio. i also installed the ingres jdbc driver manually. that finally got the problem solved.

Comment: Great, it was indeed the repository. I wasn't sure, sometime these issues are caused by proxy configuration or other problems, but a bad repo is just an issue among others. I posted a related answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed to transfer file: `https://nexus.codehaus.org/...` Seems like you configured the old Codehaus repository, but it is no longer available. Codehaus was terminated in 2015. See: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217611787-codehaus-org-Repositories-Should-Be-Removed-From-Your-Nexus-Instance

Yoy should remove that repository from your `pom.xml` and/or `settings.xml`.